# How can I find the max number with different category in this tuple?

Tags: python, list

I get some data like this

```
A=['A,1','A,2','A,4','A,5','B,2','B,3','B,4','B,5','C,2','C,20','C,200','C,2']
```

I want to have a result like this,This means the the name,the min number, the max number.I have 1 million data like this.

```
'A,1,5','B,2,5','C,2,200'
```

I tried in this way:

```
A=['A,1','A,2','A,4','A,5','B,2','B,3','B,4','B,5','C,2','C,20','C,200','C,2']
B=[]
C=[]
for r in A:
    B.append(r.split(',')[0])
B_set=list(set(B))
catagory_number=range(0,len(B_set),1)
for j in catagory_number:
    numbers = []
    for r in A:
        if B_set[j]==r.split(',')[0]:
            numbers.append(r.split(',')[1])
            print numbers
```

As you can see, it do not work, I get problem to get data together.

```
['1']
['1', '2']
['1', '2', '4']
['1', '2', '4', '5']
['2']
['2', '20']
['2', '20', '200']
['2', '20', '200', '2']
['2']
['2', '3']
['2', '3', '4']
['2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: show your approach 1st

Comment: You can have a look in this doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects. Agreed with previous comment though, please provide some code and try to avoid typo errors.

Comment: @nishantkumar Sorry, I tried the for loop, however no result, I will avoid this next time~

Comment: it's ok, we are willing to see the for loop. SO will definitely help you!

Comment: I have a solution, I'll post it if you share your attempt :)

Comment: I get stuck here for several hours..No solution for me, you want to see my wrong codes?@Chris_Rands

Comment: @cc1000ml yah sure, that way you can learn better

Comment: Then someone can edit your code and solve the problem. Most of the people here write code that is hard to read without understanding it at all. That wouldn't help you in any way.

Comment: Yes, I get this, I put on my codes, sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over your `list` and derive the min and max values using an `OrderedDict`. At the end you can re-create the string as I show, but actually you might be better off keeping the dictionary data structure (depends what you want to do next):

```
import collections

def sol(lst):
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    for item in lst:
        key, value = item.split(',')
        value = int(value)
        if key in d:
            if value < d[key][0]:
                d[key][0] = value
            elif value > d[key][0]:
                d[key][1] = value
        else:
            d[key] = [value, value] # key = letter; value = [min, max] 
    return ['{},{},{}'.format(key,*values) for key,values in d.items()] # in Python 2 use key,value[0],value[1]
```

Example:

```
my_lst = ['A,1','A,2','A,4','A,5','B,2','B,3','B,4','B,5','C,2','C,20','C,200','C,2']
print(sol(my_lst))
# ['A,1,5', 'B,2,5', 'C,2,200']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, next time I will add my 'wrong' code.

Answer (score 0):

A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a list as default value could help you a lot:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = defaultdict(list)
>>> data['A']
[]
>>> data['A'].append(1)
>>> data['A'].append(2)
>>> data['B'].append(3)
>>> data
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3]})
```

It's probably what you wanted to write with `set` and multiple loops. `defaultdict` is a standard structure and should be fast enough, even with many values.

Here's a beginning of a solution with this data structure:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

A = ['A,1','A,2','A,4','A,5','B,2','B,3','B,4','B,5','C,2','C,20','C,200','C,2']

for couple in A:
    letter, number = couple.split(',')
    data[letter].append(int(number))

print(data)
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [1, 2, 4, 5], 'C': [2, 20, 200, 2], 'B': [2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

For each letter in `A`, you now have a list of corresponding values. It shouldn't be too hard to extract `min` and `max` and write the desired list.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help, I get a problem in geeting data together This solution is good. I use max() and min() to solve the next.. @Eric Duminil

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
letter=[]
number=[]

A=['A,1','A,2','A,4','A,5','B,2','B,3','B,4','B,5','C,2','C,20','C,200','C,2']
for couple in A:
    a, b = couple.split(',')
    if a not in letter:
        letter.append(a)
        number.append([b])
    else:
        ind=letter.index(a)
        number[ind].append(b)

B=[]
i=0
while i<len(letter):
    B.append(letter[i]+","+str(min(number[i]))+","+str(max(number[i])))
    i+=1

print (B)
```

> ['A,1,5', 'B,2,5', 'C,2,200']

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you intented to do using `groupby` from `itertools` module and using `list comprehension` like this example:

```
from itertools import groupby

A = ['A,1','A,2','A,4','A,5','B,2','B,3','B,4','B,5','C,2','C,20','C,200','C,2']
sub_final = (sorted(list(v), key = lambda x: int(x.split(",")[1])) for _,v in groupby(sorted(A), lambda x: x[0]))
final = ["{0},{1}".format(k[0],k[-1].split(',')[-1]) for k in sub_final]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['A,1,5', 'B,2,5', 'C,2,200']
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the fastest but I think this is easy to read. Can't offer formatting since I'm using Python 3.4.

```
A=['A,1','A,2','A,4','A,5','B,2','B,3','B,4','B,5','C,2','C,20','C,200','C,2']

summary = {}
for a in A:
    k, v = a.split(',')
    v = int(v)
    if k in summary:
        summary[k] = (min(v, summary[k][0]), max(v, summary[k][1]))
    else:
        summary[k] = (int(v), int(v))

for k in sorted(summary.keys()):
    print (k, summary[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is to split the list on the basis of it's headers i.e. A, B, C...and find the min and max for each of them. Below is one way to do so:

`#!/usr/bin/python`

`A=['A,1','A,2','A,4','A,5','B,2','B,3','B,4','B,5','C,2','C,20','C,200','C,2']`

```
headerList = []
assoNumList = []
finalList = []

# Iterate over the list to obtain the headers i.e. A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B....C,...
for a in range(len(A)):
header = A[a][0]
headerList.append(header)

# Convert the list into a set to get distinct headers i.e. A,B,C..
headerSet = set(headerList)
uniqueHeaderList = list(headerSet)

# Iterate over the unique header list to get all numbers associated
# with each header. Apply min and max functions over the number set
# to get the Header wise Min and Max numbers.
for i in range(len(uniqueHeaderList)):
    for a in range(len(A)):
        if(A[a][0] == uniqueHeaderList[i]):
            assoNum = A[a][2:]
            assoNumList.append(assoNum)
            header = A[a][0]
    result = header+","+min(assoNumList)+","+max(assoNumList)
    finalList.append(result)
    del assoNumList[:]      

print(sorted(finalList))

#Output: ['A,1,5','B,2,5','C,2,200']
```